# Как исключить дубликаты записей при добавлении CSV файла в таблицу БД

Tags: python, база-данных, sql-server, dataframe, csv

Таблица выглядит таким образом:

```
Категория по буквам |Категория по аббревиатуре|Дата      |П_1     |П_2
____________________|_________________________|__________|________|________|
      Буквенная     |ZZZ                      |07.20.2020|2       |3
      ______________|_________________________|__________|________|________|
      Численная     |ZZZ                      |07.20.2020|1       |1
      ______________|_________________________|__________|________|________|
      Численная     |AAA                      |07.20.2020|3       |7
      ______________|_________________________|__________|________|_________
      Буквенная     |CCC                      |07.20.2020|40      |1
      ______________|_________________________|__________|________|_________
      Буквенная     |CCC                      |07.24.2020|0       |0
```

Нужно чтобы блок данных загружался в таблицу БД после проверки, что еще нет данных за сформированную дату (дубликаты данных), иначе выводится уведомление, что данные с такой датой уже существуют в БД.

Данные загружаются таким образом:

```
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=dagger;DATABASE=test;UID=user;PWD=password")

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
df.to_sql("mytable", engine, index=False, if_exists="append")
```

Comment: может построить на уровне таблицы БД уникальный индекс? Или лить в одну таблицу(временную) - потом выполнять скрипт проверки данных(на пересечение) - если он ничего не вернул - перебрасывать данные в основную таблицу?

Comment: таблицу нельзя изменить, она не моя. в моем случае лучше всего не менять БД.

Comment: насколько мне известно, единственное, что сейчас доступно - это итерирование (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30337394/pandas-to-sql-fails-on-duplicate-primary-key), что работает ОЧЕНЬ медленно. я бы посоветовал сначала читать таблицу в датафрейм, добавлять новые данные, удалять дубликаты, и потом накатывать таблицу целиком в SQL. но тут тоже есть свои минусы

Comment: хмм, а если добавлять в mssql данные, потом прочитывать ее уже в датафрейм и уже потом удалять дубликаты? это норм будет?

Comment: Если вам не критичны дубликаты на самом сервере, то писать все, а затем читать и удалять дубликаты - лучший вариант

Comment: а если критичны, то сначала читать потом сравнивать, потом записывать?

Comment: да. считать все, сравнить, почистить и дописать

Answer (score 2):

Я вижу два варианта решения:

1. заливать данные из DataFrame во **временную** таблицу и потом делать вставку с проверкой на стороне SQL Server.
2. вычитываем всю таблицу из SQL Server в DataFrame, получаем новый DataFrame с записями, которые отстутствуют в таблице SQL Server, заливаем данные обратно в таблицу.

Второй подход может быть очень медленным и со временем таблица может стать настолько большой, что она не поместится в памяти в виде DataFrame. Поэтому я бы выбрал первый вариант.

Решение:

```
import urllib
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=dagger;DATABASE=test;UID=user;PWD=password")

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
# вставляем данные во временную таблицу
df.to_sql("tmp_table", index=False, if_exists="replace")
# подготавливаем SQL для вставки уникальных записей
qry = """
INSERT INTO target_table (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT * FROM tmp_table tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM target_table tgt 
    WHERE tgt.col1 = tmp.col1 AND tgt.col2 = tmp.col2 ...
)
"""
con = engine.connect()
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(qry)
con.commit()
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ! сейчас буду пробовать. хотела уточнить: 1) df.to_sql("tmp_table", index=False, if_exists="replace") данной строчкой мы создаем новую таблицу tmp_table на стороне mssql? (то есть далее в mssql будет уже 1 временная таблица для дальнейшей загрузки других данных) 2)  SELECT 1 - что значит? я знаю только "select название_столбца"

Comment: @MRO, 1) создаем таблицу "tmp_table" в SQL Server - с этим у вас могут возникнуть проблемы, т.к. раньше вы говорили что у вас нет прав на создание таблиц. Возможно вам придется обратиться к DBA отвечающему за SQL Server и запросить его предоставить вам права на создание таблиц (безопаснее всего создать новую маленькую БД и дать вам права на создание и удаление таблиц в этой БД). В этом случае вам придется явно указывать имя БД в SQL запросе и в `df.to_sql(...)`. Или же попросить его создать таблицу для вас, но в этом случае вам придется каждый раз удалять все записи: cur.execute("DELETE ..")

Comment: я скорее всего смоту договориться на счет прав, но зачем нужно каждый раз удалять все записи во 2 случае?

Comment: при использовании `df.to_sql(..., if_exists="replace")`, Pandas делает следующее: 1) drop table tab; 2) create table tab(...); 3) insert into tab ...; Если у вас не будет прав на удаление и создание таблиц в БД, то первые две операции выдадут вам ошибки...

Comment: не разрешили дать права :( говорят делать просто запрос и смотреть есть ли там записи.

Comment: @MRO, если бы я был DBA, я бы тоже не давал никому прав удалять и создавать таблицы в продакшн БД. Именно поэтому я предложил вам вариант с созданием маленькой БД на том же сервере, где вы бы могли создавать и удалять таблицы - это гораздо безопаснее. И в качестве альтернативы - чтобы DBA создал для вас эту таблицу в основной БД. Объясните ему, что иначе вам придётся каждый раз вычитывать __всю__ таблицу. Если у вас адекватный DBA, то должен согласиться с одним из двух вариантов. ;)

Comment: мне сказали, что можно создавать таблицу через ms studio, но через python нельзя.....

Comment: @MRO, тогда не вижу особых проблем)